# Role of Augmented Images

Tags: arcore

What is the role of Augmented Images Database?

I am using arcoreimg tool to generate the img database, but why do need to generate it. I know it is a very basic question please provide your guidance

I am new to AR following Google AR SDK, Please help.

Comment: Is it about image search when we focus camera at a particular image and some other related content pops out for more details?

Answer (score 1):

The role of the `AugmentedImageDatabase` is to store a compressed representation of the images you'd like to track. This is used by ARCore to detect images in the real world.

Generating a database at compile time with the `arcoreimg` tool has several advantages:

1. Your app no longer needs to bundle the original PNG or JPEG files. Your app would instead include a smaller database file, resulting in a smaller APK size.
2. Your app no longer needs to decode the original PNG or JPEG files to extract the image's feature points at runtime. This is an operation which takes roughly [~30ms for each image](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/AugmentedImageDatabase.html#addImage(java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.Bitmap)).

Comment: I got some list of images . Instead of loading images at runtime in ARCore Augmented images , I created myImges.imgdb database at compile time. How to use the already created db in the code. I see creating image database at runtime in google ARCore documentation ,but how to use already compiled and existing .imgdb. Can anyone help regarding this.

Comment: The ARCore Java GitHub repo provides some example applications. You can place your place your image database file under your project's Assets directory, then from your activity, open an input stream to the file, then use the `AugmentedImageDatabase.deserialize` to create an object you can configure your ARCore session with:

https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/augmented_image_java/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/core/examples/java/augmentedimage/AugmentedImageActivity.java#L371

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will see this sample and will let you know